# Error: FormArray at mat-table --> can't find control on path (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, formarray, formgroups

this is my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="taskTableForm">
  <div id="divTable">
    <table mat-table formArrayName="taskDetail" [dataSource]="this.dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="action" [(ngModel)]="element.action" (valueChange)="actionEdited(element, $event)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let action of fetchService.actions" [value]="action">{{action.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is my ts:

```
 protected taskTableForm: FormGroup;

[...]
     const control = <FormArray>this.taskTableForm.controls["taskDetail"];
     const newTaskGroup: FormGroup = this.initItems();
     control.push(newTaskGroup);
[...]

public initItems(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      action: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

The Error which I get back from my debugger is:
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'taskDetails -> action'

How am I supposed to set the path right?

I have this example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155324/5545770
--> It is based on the 'normal' *table* but it should also work on the *mat-table*, right?

**[Update]**
I just set the *formGroupName* on the wrong tag

As it was:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i"></tr>
```

And as it should be:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

Comment: Cheers, matey.  Takes a bit to get your head around the cdk version.

Comment: Some relevant examples, https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxnxkdvnpny?file=app%2Ftable-row-context-example.ts.